# In my Shiny app, why does my sample generator result in the same exact sample without any randomization?

Tags: r, shiny, statistics, shiny-reactivity

Although I am able to generate the correct amount of samples, and these samples are each of the right size, each one is exactly the same.

Currently, I am trying to create a Shiny app that demonstrates the Central Limit Theorem, specifically for the case regarding the distribution of the sample mean. I expected the app to generate a proper sampling distribution when I realized that the histogram had the same exact value on the x-axis, indicating that the mean was exactly the same for each sample.

Based on my own testing, I think that the issue lies with the sample_i() reactive expression, given that the latter reactive expressions work well.

Would I have to implement another reactive expression in order to fix the issue?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Demonstration of the Central Limit Theorem"),
  fluidRow(
    column(4, selectInput("dist", "Distribution",
                          c("Normal", "Uniform", "Poisson", "Binomial"))),
    column(4, numericInput("n_sample", "Number of samples", value = 50)),
    column(4, numericInput("size", "Sample size", value = 100))
  ), 
  tabsetPanel(
    id = "params",
    type = "hidden",
    tabPanel("Normal",
             numericInput("mean", "Mean", value = 0),
             numericInput("sd", "SD", value = 1)
    ),
    tabPanel("Uniform",
             numericInput("min", "Min", value = 0),
             numericInput("max", "Max", value = 1)
    ),
    tabPanel("Poisson",
             numericInput("r", "Rate", value = 1)
    ),
    tabPanel("Binomial",
             numericInput("p", "Probability of success", value = 0.5),
             numericInput("n", "Number of trials", value = 10)
    )
  ),
  plotOutput("hist"),
  verbatimTextOutput("length")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$dist, {
    updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "params", selected = input$dist)
  })
  
  sample_i <- reactive({
    switch(input$dist, 
      Normal = rnorm(input$size, input$mean, input$sd),
      Uniform = runif(input$size, input$min, input$max), 
      Poisson = rpois(input$size, input$r), 
      Binomial = rbinom(input$size, input$n, input$p))
  })
  sample_dist <- reactive({
    replicate(n = input$n_sample, sample_i())
  })
  sample_dist_mean <- reactive({
      apply(sample_dist(), MARGIN = 2, mean) |>
        unlist() |> 
        as.numeric()
  })
  
  output$hist <- renderPlot(hist(sample_dist_mean()))
  output$length <- renderPrint(head(sample_dist(), n = 5))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Note that the console generates the output below (which was done through the length component of the output) when the number of samples is set to 12.

```
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
[1,]  0.5953571  0.5953571  0.5953571  0.5953571  0.5953571  0.5953571
[2,]  0.8323953  0.8323953  0.8323953  0.8323953  0.8323953  0.8323953
[3,] -1.0366900 -1.0366900 -1.0366900 -1.0366900 -1.0366900 -1.0366900
[4,]  2.1517537  2.1517537  2.1517537  2.1517537  2.1517537  2.1517537
[5,] -1.2565259 -1.2565259 -1.2565259 -1.2565259 -1.2565259 -1.2565259
           [,7]       [,8]       [,9]      [,10]      [,11]      [,12]
[1,]  0.5953571  0.5953571  0.5953571  0.5953571  0.5953571  0.5953571
[2,]  0.8323953  0.8323953  0.8323953  0.8323953  0.8323953  0.8323953
[3,] -1.0366900 -1.0366900 -1.0366900 -1.0366900 -1.0366900 -1.0366900
[4,]  2.1517537  2.1517537  2.1517537  2.1517537  2.1517537  2.1517537
[5,] -1.2565259 -1.2565259 -1.2565259 -1.2565259 -1.2565259 -1.2565259
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Found a new solution.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$dist, {
    updateTabsetPanel(inputId = "params", selected = input$dist)
  })
  
  samples <- reactive({
    switch(input$dist, 
      Normal = replicate(n = input$n_sample, rnorm(input$size, input$mean, input$sd)),
      Uniform = replicate(n = input$n_sample, runif(input$size, input$min, input$max)), 
      Poisson = replicate(n = input$n_sample, rpois(input$size, input$r)), 
      Binomial = replicate(n = input$n_sample, rbinom(input$size, input$n, input$p)))
  })

  sample_dist_mean <- reactive({
      apply(samples(), MARGIN = 2, mean) |>
        unlist() |> 
        as.numeric()
  })
  
  output$hist <- renderPlot(hist(sample_dist_mean()))
}
```